# having dstore Filter operator throws compiler error

Tags: javascript, dojo, google-closure-compiler, dgrid, dstore

I have the following code in my project using dstore and dgrid. When I use the filter operators I get compile error in eclipse as well as Closure compiler that comes with Dojo build.

```
storeFilter =  new origStore.Filter().or(new origStore.Filter().in('category', ['Action', 'Thriller', 'Comedy']), new origStore.Filter().eq('newRelease', true));

grid.set('collection', origStore.filter(storeFilter));
```

Eclispe Error: Syntax error on token '.', Identifier expected after this token.

Closure compiler: error at '.in', Identifier expected.

Compiling dgrid and dstore packages using closure compiler goes smoothly. But when I compile my package with above code result in error.

I also want to note that the code works as expected in all browsers.

Could any of you shed some light here.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `.in` with `['in']`, since `in` is a reserved word.

Comment: In ES5 or higher, properties are allowed to be reserved words. The compiler's `language_in` flag may just need to be used to specify a `ECMASCRIPT5` or higher. Newer compiler releases default to ES6.

Comment: I have the language_in property set to ECMASCRIPT5 in the build.xml. <arg value="language_in=ECMASCRIPT5" /> but there is no effect.

Comment: My guess is you are using Ant and you need to use the ant option value "languageIn" rather than the flag name "language_in".  Regardless, Chad is correct, the compiler is running in the ES3 language mode and you need to change it.  If you aren't using the command-line runner you need to figure out how your tool does that.

Comment: I changed code as Ken suggested, it works. Since I use old version, it may be default to ES3 mode and I get errors for having trailing comma in array values. Let me try changing to languageIn. is there a link where I can learn about using command-line mode that process all the js files under a folder and its subfolder? thank you so much.